# Can I swap active/neutral on an isolated 240V power supply?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, mains, neutral

I'm looking at using a Meanwell IRM-03 isolated switchmode power supply ([datasheet](http://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/IRM-03/IRM-03-SPEC.PDF)) in a project but the active/neutral pins are arranged in an inconvenient way for the PCB tracks. It would be a heap easier to route the board if I swapped those connections.

Is there any reason I shouldn't just swap them? Most of the discussion I can find around the topic refers to equipment where swapping them means the neutral is switched, making it dangerous.

Similar power supplies are used in countries with non-polarised 2 pin power sockets (eg USA) - in that case I imagine it could get plugged in either way with no ill effects.

Comment: datasheet http://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/IRM-03/IRM-03-SPEC.PDF says there is no frame ground (FG) pin. So it is possible it was designed to be used in either orientation. I guess rectifier would ensure that neutral is not switched.

Comment: If it truly is an isolated supply, meaning an ohm meter shows no connection between the AC input and DC output, then you are safe. There can be leakage currents, but in the low micro-amps.